# binding date textbox to a date field

Tags: angularjs

I have a <input type="date" ng-model="dateOfBirth"> that I want to bind to a DateOfBirth property that came from a c# class serialized as json (asp.net mvc app). Somehow angular does not think that my property is of type date (the c# one is DateTime) and the binding does not work. What do I need to do to properly handle DateTime properties? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular just wants a regular javascript Date(). Try to wrap it in Date.parse() make sure you are getting a proper js date and angular will handle it's formatting and everything from there.

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(date_as_str));
```